# error: overloaded method value get with alternatives in getting a point on an image

Tags: image, scala

I am using this:

```
 var res = new Array[Byte](1)
 var u=image.get(p.x,p.y,res)
```

where:

```
val image= new Mat
var p=new Point (3,32)
```

and having error said: " overloaded method value get with alternatives"
Can't figure out the problem. Please help me on that!

Thanks!

Comment: What is `image` ? How is it declared? This is not enough code.

Comment: Image is a Mat structure in Opencv

Comment: what's `p`? You really need to post a full example. How are we supposed to know what libraries you're using and what objects you're instantiating?

Comment: I am sorry about that I am editing it now!

Comment: This snippets look ok. Please post more code and the entire error message, including the line it is referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.opencv.org/java/

Points have double fields, but get takes ints.

```
image.get(p.x.toInt, p.y.toInt, res)
```

(Untested, of course.)